# JavaScript Regex - Whitespace, comma and slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Would like to replace all instances of whitespace, commas and slashes in a string with a hyphen.

At the moment I am using

```
myString..replace(/\s+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "-").replace(/,/,"-");
```

which is not nice I know but I tried something along the lines of

```
myString.replace(/s+,\//g, "-");
```

but to no avail.

How should I organise the regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put all inside a char class except `\s+`.

```
myString.replace(/\s+|[,\/]/g, "-");
```

Comment: @zerkms no, he wants to replace one or more spaces with `-` or exactly one comma and `/` with `-`

Comment: Thank you :-) Have to wait before I can accept. May I ask, why do we have the '|' character in the regex?

Comment: Why _except `\s+`_? `\s` might be inside a char class too, though without quantifier: `[\s,\/]`

Comment: @hindmost then how you apply `+` for only `\s` ?

Comment: There is no need in quantifier at all in the OP's case. AFAIU he don't need distinguish whitespace from other qualified chars: _all instances of whitespace, commas and slashes..._